# Import project on eclipse using maven plug-in

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to import an existing project on eclipse using maven plugin m2eclipse. However, I don't know how to do it. I woulld aprreciate it if somebody can explain it to me.

Currently using eclipse 3.6

Many thanks,

Comment: You should use Eclipse Keppler (4.3) and m2e Plugin which solves many issues. Otherwise your are fighting with old bugs.

Answer (score 0):

file -> import -> existing maven project -> browse to your directory (the one with the `pom.xml`) and select your project in the projects window.

Comment: I keep getting loads of errors, eventhough the build by other team members was sucessful on Bamboo. What do you think I'm missing here?

Comment: No idea if you don't precise on your post what are the errors you encounter.